# Create csv columns based on existing csv column value

Tags: powershell

Below is the existing csv i have

```
InterfaceID         A_IP              A_Hostname             B_IP        B_Hostname
14474             10.10.90.6         lnx0408.com          17.11.12.3    DEPC0322.com
14474             10.20.90.6         lnx0409.com          17.11.12.4    DEPC0323.com


12527             10.30.90.6         lnx0410.com          17.11.12.5    DEPC0324.com
12527             10.40.90.6         lnx0411.com          17.11.12.6    DEPC0325.com
```

In a text file i have the location details for this interface location like below separated by **"tab"**

```
Neuremburg  Masergy 20  14474
Madrid  Masergy 40  12527
```

Now i need to fetch the first two values from the text file based on InterfaceID value from csv and create 2 columns. so the desired output should be like below

```
InterfaceID   City             region                   A_IP              A_Hostname             B_IP        B_Hostname
14474         Neuremburg       Masergy                 10.10.90.6        lnx0408.com          17.11.12.3    DEPC0322.com
14474         Neuremburg       Masergy                 10.20.90.6        lnx0409.com          17.11.12.4    DEPC0323.com


12527         Madrid           Masergy                 10.30.90.6        lnx0410.com          17.11.12.5    DEPC0324.com
12527         Madrid           Masergy                 10.40.90.6        lnx0411.com          17.11.12.6    DEPC0325.com
```

Please need help in how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your files as csv, loop through each line in your main file and do a simple lookup with `Where-Object` - as it is an object, then collect that stuff in `$fetchedOutput` - also delimited - convert it back and output as table.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "yourCSV" -Delimiter "`t"
$textfile = Import-Csv -Path "yourTextfile" -Delimiter "`t" -Header "City","Region","Something","InterfaceID"

$fetchedOutput = Foreach($c in $csv){

    $cInterfaceId = $c.InterfaceID
    $cA_IP = $c.A_IP
    $cA_Hostname = $c.A_Hostname
    $cB_IP = $c.B_IP
    $cB_Hostname = $c.B_Hostname

    $cCityAndReg = $txt | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceID -eq $cInterfaceId}

    "$cInterfaceId;$($cCityAndReg.City);$($cCityAndReg.Region);$cA_IP;$cA_Hostname;$cB_IP;$cB_Hostname"

}

$fetchedOutput | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Header "InterfaceID","City","Region","A_IP","A_Hostname","B_IP","B_Hostname" | Format-Table
```